# sort row of a matrix in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, row, nearest-neighbor

I have this matrix of distances. I want to sort the values in the rows in ascending order so row 1 should look like
`388.8342 396.9244 405.8091 423.8408 480.4186 487.3038`

The 2nd row also should be sorted in ascending order

[image]

I tried doing `nearest <- distances[order(distances)]
nearest` but it is not the result that I want.

Comment: `apply(distances,1,sort)`

Comment: Share data with `dput()` not images.